# Passing java Strings to html or jsp as place holder for form

Tags: java, html, jsp

Currently I'm making a car rental app and right now I'm grabbing the id from a button on a table of data. The form data passes the id to the back, the id is how I am querying the back end to capture the strings needed. and now I'm trying to re-rout to a new HTML page and place these strings ready to be updated in a place holder on html. The servlet is as follows.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String carid = req.getParameter("id");
    String year;
    String make;
    String model;
    String color;

    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement st = null;

    try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        Context env = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env");
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) env.lookup("jdbc/carRentalSystem");
        conn = ds.getConnection();
        st = conn.createStatement();

        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cardetails where id='" + carid + "'");
        if (rs.next()) {
            year = rs.getString("Year");
            make = rs.getString("Make");
            model = rs.getString("Model");
            color = rs.getString("color");

        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid password, please try again");
            res.sendRedirect("login.html");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (st != null) st.close();
        } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) { }
        try {
            if (conn != null) conn.close();
        } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) { }
        try {
            if (rs != null) rs.close();
        } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what this question is asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was attempting to redirect to a different page sorry for the confusion.